# Python write database to csv

Tags: python, mysql, json, csv

I am fetching data from a MySQL database and writing into a CSV file.
This looks like this :

```
with open("output.csv", "ab+") as csv_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        csv_writer.writerows(db_cursor)
```

This works fine with normal columns. However, I have a column which is of type `LONGTEXT` and has JSON data in it.

csv_writer adds extra quotes around each key value in the JSON when it creates the CSV file.

i.e., if my column has this value :
`{"key":"value"}`

the output.csv file has :
`"{""key"" : ""value""}"`

What I want is :
`"{\"key\" : \"value\"}"`

How do I achieve this ?

(I have to read this file again in a ruby app and recreate the json. With this extra quotes, I am not sure how do I handle that!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To specify how the output should be formatted, you need to pass the correct [formatting parameters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params) when creating the writer, or create you own dialect and use that.

In your case, you'll probably want something like this:

```
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file,
                        doublequote=False,
                        escapechar='\\',
                        quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```

This uses the default (`excel`) dialect while overriding the supplied parameters.